# Translate a point until it reaches surface PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've tried a few different ways to extend my lines (4326) out by 300 meters on each end (straight lines with only 2 vertices). One way was to buffer each end point by 300 meters (since st_buffer can do meters by casting to geography) and then getting st_longestline from the two buffer circles. The problem is that sometimes these lines end up being at a different angle from the original and using st_snap (snapping the longest line to the original) is giving me really weird results. So now I'm wondering if I can translate the endpoints in the direction I want and use snap so that they snap to the buffer circle of each endpoint. This way the new endpoints should be 300 meters away, and also in the correct direction.

Comment: this sounds like something that shouldn't be attempted in a geographic coordinate system

Comment: @IanTurton can you elaborate? I am only using the geography type to buffer, after that I switch back to geometry.

Comment: but your data is stored in degrees on a spherical or ellipsoidal earth - reproject to a Cartesian plane and do the trigonometry there and then project back

Comment: @IanTurton I may go that route, but just to increase my understanding can you explain what would be wrong with using geography type for this purpose? isn't that what it is for? Lets say I was only using to buffer out a geometry and nothing else, is that still problematic for 4326 geometries?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449440/st-buffer-giving-inaccurate-results-but-why for a discussion of what can go wrong